# drawing in the UIImageView moves up after every stroke

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am following the tutorial to create a simple drawing pad app (http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit#comments)

The app has a single UIViewController and a UIImageView in it. After implementing touchBegin, touchMoved, and touchEnd, I could draw but after every stroke ends, the whole picture moves up. So after several strokes, the whole picture will be distorted and squeezed to the very top of the screen. Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.lastPoint =[touch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.mouseSwiped = YES;
    //find out the position where the touch event happened
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    //Setup the drawing context and prepare to draw something
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

    //Create a drawing area that is of the same size as the view dimensions
    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    //Set the drawing starting point
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.lastPoint.x, self.lastPoint.y);

    //Setup a line from the starting point to specified point, i.e current point in this case
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

    //Set the drawing style
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.brush);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.red, self.green, self.blue, 1);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeNormal);


    //Paint the line
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    self.mainImage.image=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.mainImage setAlpha:self.opacity];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    if(!self.mouseSwiped){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:
         CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.brush);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
                                   self.red, self.green, self.blue, self.opacity);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.lastPoint.x, self.lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.lastPoint.x, self.lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);

    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:self.opacity];
    self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: Are your views both the same size?

Comment: @Wain:Thank you for your comments. It worked (the drawing stopped drifting up) after changing: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size); to
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a mismatch between the size of the 2 views you're using, so as you move between the 2 different coordinate spaces you get a scaling effect.